# How to save images from QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, image, qt, qgraphicsview, image-editor

I'm creating a very simple image editor on Qt. The user can open an image(the image is displayed on a `QGraphicsView`) and he has the ability to rotate either clockwise or counterclockwise.Then he can save the rotated image.Here lies my problem.How can i get the rotated image displayed in the `QGraphicsView` and then save it?

Here is my code of opening the image file.The variable image is `QPixmap` type and the imageObject is a `QImage` pointer.

[image: Opening Image Code]

Comment: Instead of using an image of your code, why not just post the code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to create a `QPixmap` and then use a `QPainter` to paint the `QGraphicsScene` onto the pixmap.

```
# Get the size of your graphicsview
rect = graphicsview.viewport().rect()

# Create a pixmap the same size as your graphicsview
# You can make this larger or smaller if you want.
pixmap = QPixmap(rect.size())
painter = QPainter(pixmap)

# Render the graphicsview onto the pixmap and save it out.
graphicsview.render(painter, pixmap.rect(), rect)
pixmap.save('/path/to/file.png')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot you been very helpful at last it worked! @BrendanAbel

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#render):

```
void QGraphicsView::render(QPainter * painter, const QRectF & target = QRectF(), const QRect & source = QRect(), Qt::AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode = Qt::KeepAspectRatio)
```

> Renders the source rect, which is in view coordinates, from the scene
>   into target, which is in paint device coordinates, using painter. This
>   function is useful for capturing the contents of the view onto a paint
>   device, such as a QImage (e.g., to take a screenshot)

As for the rotation, the method you need is `void QGraphicsItem::setRotation(qreal angle)` or alternatively `void QGraphicsView::rotate(qreal angle)` - depending on whether you want to rotate the item or the entire view.